# Can I make Ctrl-C in a child process do some actions in the parent process?

Tags: linux, shell-script, signals

I work on a web application which uses `memcache`, `mongodb`  etc along with a `python` based web framework. `python` needs to be in foreground so that I can see the console output, or enter debugger if required.

Currently I have a `start.sh`

```
memcache_start
mongodb_start
python fg
```

and `stop.sh`

```
memcache_stop
mongodb_stop
```

scripts that does automates everything.

Normaly I kill the `python` in fg using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> which kills the `python`. Now I need to explicitly run the `stop.sh` to bring the system down gracefully.

Is it possible for start.sh to be aware of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> `SIGINT` so that I can execute the stop commands as well since it is logically the next successive action that has to be performed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `trap ' ' INT` before running python to tell your shell to ignore SIGINT and `trap - INT` afterwards to restore default behavior:

```
memcache_start
mongodb_start
trap ' ' INT
python fg
trap - INT
memcache_stop
mongodb_stop
```

After the `trap ' ' INT` line the shell is instructed to ignore SIGINT, but `python` is not affected by this. So, when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, `python` quits normally, but the shell carries on, executing the remaining cleanup commands of your script. The second command, `trap - INT` is not strictly required, it enables you to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> again to stop the cleanup process. That is, if you send SIGINT to `memcache_stop`, the shell won't try to execute `mongodb_stop` and will simply quit.

[Here](https://www.cons.org/cracauer/sigint.html)'s a detailed article describing how SIGINT/SIGQUIT are handled by shells.

Comment: This is simply BRILLIANT. I don't understand what you mean though. Can you explain a little more in detail or give a pointer to read?

Comment: @Nishant I have edited my answer, hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @DmitryGrigoryev really appreciate. That's more than enough pointers to understand this better.